# MVC4 and multiple windows azure web roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-roles

I have 2 web roles in my  MVC4 project and would like to set up the routing such a way that All requests for  www.mysite.com/api /  should be routed roleA and any other requests should be routed to roleB. ( reason for such a setup being we can independently scale the api or the UI role instances , please feel to discredit the idea if needed )
Also if I had a third webrole hosted as a subdomain  of mysite.com i.e admin.mysite.com  can I route the requests from  www.mysite.com/admin to admin.mysite.com . If so, is there guidance on how to setup the dev environments.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options here:

- Run all web applications on the same WebRole and use host headers to allow access to each web application through the use of host headers (api.mysite.com for example). Besides host headers you can add virtual directories to the main web application (mysite.com/api). More info: [How to Configure a Web Role for Multiple Web Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx). (*This may not be the solution you're looking for since you want to independently scale the web applications*)
- Use different cloud services. You cannot use the same endpoint (port 80 for example) for more than one role in the same cloud service. If you want multiple Web Roles using the same endpoint you'll need to split these over multiple cloud services. This will allow you to scale instances independently and by using a CNAME for each cloud service you can have something like this: **mysite.cloudapp.net** => **www.mysite.com**, **mysiteadmin.cloudapp.net** => **admin.mysite.com**, **mysiteapi.cloudapp.net** => **api.mysite.com**. Using [ARR](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) you can even use virtual directories like **www.mysite.com/api** and route the request to api.mysite.com
- Create 3 WebRoles: MySiteWebRole, ApiWebRole, AdminWebRole. MySiteWebRole would have an input Http endpoint (port 80), and the other ones would use another port (Input, in order to use the load balancer). Using ARR on MySiteWebRole you can redirect the requests to ApiWebRole and AdminWebRole. Example: All requests to api.mysite.com would be routed to mysite.cloudapp.net:5838 using ARR.